Unable to reproduce armature bone rotations from .bvh import
I am trying to format the bone rotations of an armature in the way they are formatted inside of a .bvh mocap file. I thought I would be able to obtain the 3D Euler rotations as they seem to be written in a .bvh line by simply doing something like:
>>> test = bpy.data.objects['sample']
>>> for bone in test.pose.bones:
...     bones_degrees = [math.degrees(rot) for rot in list(bone.rotation_euler)]

where ‘sample’ is an armature obtained by importing a single-frame .bvh file. However, this yields very different numbers than are written in the .bvh file.
To get an idea of some rotation or axis flip that I was missing I wrote a simple script to convert the rotations I found with the above method back into a new .bvh file and then import this into the scene, but this yielded wrong armatures, not just rotated or flipped ones.
Additionally, I tried looking through the Blender source code for the way in which armatures are able to be exported as .bvh files, but I didn't find a solution there either.
Ultimately, I want to obtain rotations I could write back into a .bvh file with something like:
row = '{} {} {} '.format(root_pos[0], root_pos[1], root_pos[2])

for bone in pose_bones:
    euler = bone.rotation_euler
    row += f"{math.degrees(euler.z)} {math.degrees(euler.y)} {math.degrees(euler.x)} 

(working with ZYX files so would prefer to keep this rotation mode)
Am I missing some relative orientation that differs between .bvh formatting and Blender’s armature structure? How do I achieve this?
